# Why do I need to initialize a value for totalBill when using if else statement but not when using switch case

Tags: java, if-statement, variables, switch-statement

So I wrote two programs that do the same thing. One of them uses if-else, while the other uses switch-case.

```
public static void calcBill(String userChoice, int userMinute){
        double PackageArate = 39.99;
        double PackageBrate = 59.99;
        double PackageCrate = 69.99;

        int PackageAmins = 450;
        int PackageBmins = 900;

        double totalBill = 0.0;

        if(userChoice.equals("A")){
            if(userMinute > PackageAmins){
                int extraMins = userMinute - PackageAmins;
                totalBill = PackageArate + (extraMins * 0.45);
            } else {
                totalBill = PackageArate;
            }
        } else if (userChoice.equals("B")){
            if(userMinute > PackageBmins){
                int extraMins = userMinute - PackageBmins;
                totalBill = PackageBrate + (extraMins * 0.40);
            } else{
                totalBill = PackageBrate;
            }
        } else if(userChoice.equals("C")){
            totalBill = PackageCrate;
        } else{
            System.out.print("Invalid input.");
        }
        System.out.printf("Your bill is $%.2f%n", totalBill);
    }
```

```
    public static void calcBill(String packageChoice, int minutes){
        double packageArate = 39.99;
        double packageBrate = 59.99;
        double packageCrate = 69.99;
        
        int packageAmins = 450;
        int packageBmins = 900;
        
        double totalBill;
        
        switch(packageChoice){
            case "A":
                if(minutes > packageAmins){
                    int extraMinutes = minutes - packageAmins;
                    totalBill = packageArate + (extraMinutes * 0.45);
                } 
                else{
                    totalBill = packageArate;
                }
                break;
            case "B":
                if(minutes > packageBmins){
                    int extraMinutes = minutes - packageBmins;
                    totalBill = packageArate + (extraMinutes * 0.40);
                } 
                else{
                    totalBill = packageBrate;
                }
                break;
            case "C":
                totalBill = packageCrate;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Invalid choice.");
                return;
            
        }
```

Why do I need to initialize a value for totalBill when using if-else but not switch-case.

When I tried to not initialize a value for totalBill in the if-else, I got an error saying that the variable was not initialized.

Comment: In the `switch` code you don't use `totalBill`.  Try including the last line from the `if` code: `System.out.printf("Your bill is $%.2f%n", totalBill);`

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference - the 'default' returns. So any path that gets you past the switch statement has executed an assignment to totalBill.

Comment: Add a `return;` to your last `else` (where you have `System.out.print("Invalid input.");` -- notice your `default` in the `switch` version does not `break`. It `return`s) and then your two methods would be equivalent and you can just do `double totalBill;`

Answer (score 1):

There is a path through your 'if-else' code where you attempt to print out the value of 'totalBill', which was never assigned to. That's the path when you execute the final 'else' clause.

There is no such path in the 'switch' code. Either you assign a value, or else you return from the 'default' case before any (not shown) printing of the total.

Thus, the two implementations are not equivalent. Only you know which one has the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The last `printf` possible encountered an ininitialized variable. If instead of the `return` you do a `break` in the default, you would encountered the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have an error accused by the compiler, where the problem itself is in the instruction "System.out.printf("Your bill is $%.2f%n",totalBill);" which the second program does not have, when trying to add this to the second program you will get the same error.